# Convert Unixtime to MMddyyyy

Tags: sql, impala

I'm trying to convert a column which has unixtime (ex 1542862806000) to regular DTS

```
select unix_timestamp(column_name) from table;
```

But i get error:

```
AnalysisException: No matching function with signature: unix_timestamp(BIGINT).
```

My column type is bigint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [`from_unixtime`](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/impala_datetime_functions.html) not `unix_timestamp`.

```
select from_unixtime(cast(column_name/1000 as bigint),'MMddyyyy') 
from table
```

`unix_timestamp` converts a date/date format string to a `bigint` representing the number of seconds since `1970-01-01 00:00:00` UTC.

`from_unixtime` takes a `bigint` input and converts it to the required date format.

Comment: i forgot the second argument. try the edited version.

Comment: Now I get NULL values

Comment: you should divide the input by 1000, based on the input shown.